# What is delay time of ADC/DAC?

Tags: adc, dac

Definition given in my notes by my college-:

> B. Delay Time
> It is the time interval between the instant when the digital input changes and the instant when
> the analog output passes a specified value that is close to its initial value.

What does this mean?

1. What does digital input changing means?
2. What does analog output passing specificed value close to initial value mean?

Comment: Get a copy of Art of Electronics

Comment: What did your college (or colleague?) say when you asked. Oh, you didn't ask? Why not? It is prefectly normal to ask and make sure you're talking about the same thing. Suppose you misinterpret, find the wrong result and waste an hour. It is better to spend a couple of minutes to get clarity.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

image from https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372458D-01/lvsysidconcepts/si_step_response/

Here is a graph showing the possible output from a DAC, following a change to the DAC data.

1. Note that according to the type of DAC, this could mean the data pins of the DAC changing, or it could mean a latch signal to the DAC becoming active to enable a previously loaded data word. In a more complicated DAC, say one with a JESD interface, it could be timed from an internal counter keeping track of a shift register of data. Whatever the details, we choose a reference time that we control, causes the DAC output to change, and has a consistent time to that change.
2. The delay is measured up to the time when the output starts moving away from its previous value, that is, passing a value close to its original value. The previous value was used for some reason. Once it has changed enough, it's no longer usable.

We rarely worry too much about the delay time. Once we've decided to change the output of a DAC, we are rarely interested in how long the previous conditions would remain valid for. There will be some time-critical applications where it is needed though.

We are more usually concerned with the settling time of a DAC, the time until it gets to within some tolerance of the final steady state. The tolerance depends on the application, you often see figures of 1% and 0.1% used as defaults in data sheets, but it's always your application that will define what really matters.

Answer (score 1):

A DAC, short for digital-to-analog converter, is an element that converts a number (digital input) to an analog value (analog output).

For example, a 10-bit DAC has `2^10 = 1024` different levels it can generate on the output, usually (but not necessary) equally spaced from `0 V` to `VDD`. Here are few examples:

```
 Input    Output
+--------+--------+
 0        0.0 Vdd
 512      0.5 Vdd
 1023     1.0 Vdd
```

The delay is time measured from when the digital input is provided to when the voltage on the output reaches steady state (final) value. On a microcontroller, you provide this value by writing a number to a specified registers. There are DACs as standalone chips as well, and in that case you provide a number via some communication protocol, usually I2C or SPI. In modern microcontrollers, this time is usually in the range from nanoseconds to microseconds. For standalone chips, the question is how the delay time is calculated - from when you start sending the data or from when the chip receives the data. But the main point remains the same, you just need to agree on the definition of the "delay time".

In order to understand where this delay is coming from, try to imagine how a DAC is built from the inside. There are different designs, but the most simple one would include a lot of resistors that form voltage dividers, and a switch for each discrete level (number). Needless to say, this implementation is not very efficient, but it is simple! With all these resistors your voltage source impedance is not very good, so try adding an operational amplifier used as a buffer. Now you already have a lot of elements in the loop that contribute to the final delay.

The story for the ADC is similar, even simpler to understand. Try studying different ADC technologies such as SAR, Flash etc. and you will get a feeling where the delay is coming from.

Comment: No, that would be "settling time". According to the OP's definition "delay time" is how long the output remains at its old value before it starts to change to the new value.

Comment: Sure, you are technically right. But by reading his question one can say that the OP still does not understand fundamentals of how digital and analog circuits operate, and IMO involving "settling time" in the explanation would only complicate the explanation. Btw the definition from the OP's book/notes seems to agree with this approach.